# php page not showing anything

Tags: php, html

im trying to create a drop down many and populate the options from fields in a database that i have.
So far i have got the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");

$query = "SELECT Category FROM books";
$result = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $query);

echo "<select name=dropdown value=''>Dropdown</option>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option value=$row[Category]>$row[Category]</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However when i try to view the page nothing seems to happen.
My page remains blank and all i see is the color that i gave to the body in the css file.

Was wondering if anyone knew wh this was happening and if they can sort it out?

Thanks!

Comment: white page of death, error reporting\display are off, turn them on `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Definitely a quotes method issue.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? Does it run your config.php file? Does this file has the `html` extension and if so is your server configured to treat html files as php ?

Comment: Where do i put that code?

Comment: my config.php runs file as i have other php files that use it. this file has a .php extension

Comment: put the code dagon gave you at the top of the file.

Comment: Still nothing, stays blank.

Comment: remove all the lines, add then back in one at a time, test after each. i dont know how other people code but i test almost every line as i go.

Comment: Nope still nothing, just the normal errors telling me that theres undefined variables etc but thats due to me deleting the lines.

Comment: it seems your 'nothing' is still something. help us help you

Comment: `echo "<option value=$row[Category]>$row[Category]</option>";` - Again, quotes. There are none. These are being treated as constants `[Category]`

Comment: @Fred-ii- where would i put the quotes?
and Dagon ive tried a few times but i dont seem to get any errors other than normal syntax errors when removing the lines

Comment: help me @Fred-ii- Kanobi your my only hope

Comment: view source -thats the real meat

Comment: Actually, the quoting around your variables *is* correct. You *should* however quote your HTML attribute. `echo "<option value=\"$row[Category]\">$row[Category]</option>";` secondly, you should HTML-encode any vars you echo to be safe: `$category=htmlspecialchars($row['Category']);echo "<option value=\"$category\">$category</option>";` Again, this has nothing to do with why you're getting a white page.

Comment: its not white, he just wont tell us what he actully gets

Comment: Well @Mark thats seemed to work in a sense however now the values are appearing as plain text and not in a drop down menu.

Comment: @Dagon I dont get anything :/ i just get a blank html page with a css coloured background.

Comment: that's not blank, how is it **blank** then you go on to say with ...

Comment: out to lunch, can't help someone that cant describe the problem

Comment: by blank i mean nothing useful appears. I didnt think a coloured background would have anything to do with the problem im having.

Comment: @Dagon Even Freddy Wan Kanobi needs some TV time ;-)

Comment: @resontant81 Colour is *extremely* relevant. It means that HTML and CSS has been sent to the page. I did not error out before getting that far.

Comment: Ah sorry. Ive managed to get it to work now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are getting results from your query. Can find out by print_r($result). Think you are getting death screen because of quotes and missing opening  for first option in dropdown.

```
echo '<select name="dropdown" value=""><option value="">Dropdown</option>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['Category'] . '">' . $row['Category'] . '"</option>';
    }

    echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Oh never mind managed to get it working thanks shad!